# Practical Javascript MVC example - can the controller directly work on the view or only the model

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I am rendering tables using javascript with a model, view, controller, and events.

I need to calculate a sum across table rows and put that value in a 'sum' column. Easy enough....

I can do this in one of two ways:

Using the Controller I can copy the view data to the model, calculate the sum using data stored model and store the sum in the model, then fire an event that the model changed, which the view will pick up and re-render the table.

Or I can directly access the table view from the controller to calculate the sum, and put the sum into the sum column. Then I can copy the view over to the model.

Both methods work, however the first method interferes with the cell focus as the table is re-rendered. On keyup the table is re-rendered.  The second method works flawlessly from a user perspective.

My understanding is that the first method is the textbook approach, and it might be incorrect to re-render the entire table, but that was just easier.

here is the code:

```
//Method 1 - interferes with user input
//controller.copyTable() is already fired onkeyup
controller.model.tdo[row].sizes.data.forEach(size =>{
    sum += math.myParseFloat(size);
});
controller.model.tdo[row]['qty']['data'] = sum;
controller.model.modelChanged.notify(); //re-render of the table will occur

//method 2... works like a charm
controller.view.elements[row]['sizes'].forEach(size =>{
    sum += math.myParseFloat(size.value);
});
controller.view.elements[row]['qty'] = sum;
controller.copyTable();
```

Any thoughts? I am thinking working directly on the view is actually better, and it may just be a javascript thing....or maybe i need to re-look at how I re-rendered the table.